# Catch block for IO Exception not showing message when using BufferedReader

Tags: java, try-catch, ioexception

I'm new to Java and programming and trying to understand catch blocks. I've been playing around with this bit of code.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a new buffered reader to read user input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name;
    try{
      name = br.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("There was a problem");
      return;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Hello " + name );

  }
}
```

As I understand it, I have to use a catch block with BufferedReader to catch the IO Exception, however when I try to execute the catch block by just hitting return, it doesn't execute the catch block and print out the message, rather it prints out last line, with name empty. I've tried putting Exception rather than IOException. If I put Exception rather than IOException I get exit status 143, rather than it executing catch block.

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong, or probably more importantly what I'm not understanding?

Comment: An empty line is not invalid input. I'm not sure why you expected entering an empty line by just pressing enter to throw an exception.

Comment: In very colloquial terms: Exceptions happen when something in your program goes wrong, like trying to read in a file that doesn't exist or reading from a Reader that is already closed and therefor can no longer be used. Entering an empty line is not one of those cases.

Comment: Please state the basis for your belief that an empty line should cause an exception. I can't find it in the Javadoc. On the other hand you should certainly check for `readLine()` returning `null`, which *is* documented, and you aren't doing. Furthermore the code that prints the line should be inside the `try` block, as it depends on the success of the `try` block. Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the user to enter their `name` then you can do this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String name = "";
    while (name.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            System.out.print("What is your name?");
            name = br.readLine().trim();

            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Name cannot be empty. Please try again.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
```

Comment: BTW `readLine()` will return `null` if input is closed, and calling `trim()` on it will cause a NullPointerException in that case

Comment: Thank you all, this has helped me understand this much better.